# Stored Procedure to grab most recent database entry with one parameter?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm quite a noob at SQL queries and have trouble writing them.

I need one query that I can pass in a parameter (`Description`) and it will return the most recent item from the database for that.

- MSSQL
- Database table: `dbo.Document`
- Columns: `DocumentID (int), Description (nvarchar(255)), CreatedDate (datetime)`

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Document 
WHERE Description = "HelpDocument", 
      select * from (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID order by CreatedDate desc)
```

Comment: Depending of platform to get first row you need to use `LIMIT 1` (mysql) or `TOP 1` (MSSQL). Table has `dbo` prefix from schema, so I am guessing that your using MSSQL. You could provide this information as it is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM dbo.Document 
WHERE Description = @yourparameter
ORDER BY CreatedDate desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you need a recent item, if you don't have any PRIMARY `id` key in your table, you can use `LIMIT 1` to retrieve the most recently added item.

So I think your query might look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Document 
WHERE Description = "HelpDocument", 
      select * from (RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentID order by CreatedDate desc)
LIMIT 1
```